# Preloader - But only on homepage / first time

Tags: javascript, html

I am workin on a photography website which should display a preloader with my logo. I've implemented this already.

But now it shows up on every page.

I would like to have it only the first time someone access the website, so when he switches through subpages, no preloader shows up. Also when he switches to the home = no preloader. But when he closes the site and access it again - the preloader should be visible.

Is there a good solution for realising that?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Cookies could be a good option. A different option would be to place the preloader on the index and redirect from there to a different page which is "home", and which is linked directly from the other pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:
Suppose your website home page url is '**http://www.mywebsite.com**', then

```
if(location.href == "http://www.mywebsite.com"){
    // Display preloader
}else{
    // Hide preloader
}
```